# How to implement a sandbox for an online-judge system?

Tags: python, security, sandbox, ptrace

OJ(Online Judge)s allow users to upload arbitrary code snippet to execute on the server, but it also has a sandbox to prevent malicious code from running. For instance, on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/), if I submit this code in python:

```
import subprocess
res = subprocess.check_output(["ls", "/"])
print res
```

It returns:

```
Line 36: OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

If I want to implement the OJ system in python, is there any way to monitor the system calls of a sub-process, and forbid certain calls?

I have searched around, most posts mentioned either using ptrace or running the script within a virtual machine. I am wondering if there is a better approach.

*Note: Since OJs support uploading programs of different languages (C/python/Java), restricting the python code (like `exec` the code in a limited scope) does not work.*